# How to draw multiple strings from a list with PDFSharp without them overlapping?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I have a list **itemDescList** that contains n number of strings. In **pdfCreate**, the app draws a rectangle and in the same rectangle it draws a string or multiple. My problem is when I tried it like this, the strings overlap when I need them to be one under the other. I understand why this isn't working - **foreach** string in the list it gets drawn on the same position, however I cannot figure out how to do this. Any ideas?

```
rect = new XRect(35, 320, 300, 125);
gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.SeaShell, rect);
tf.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Center;
foreach (string item in itemDescList)
{
    tf.DrawString(item + "\n", invoiceItemsFont, XBrushes.Black, rect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
}
```

Comment: You need to build a new XRect each time and change the top value by the height of a typical letter.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this question. Here's the answer:

```
yBase = 320;
yOffset = 0;
lineHeight = 15;
rect = new XRect(340, yBase, 30, 155);
gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.SeaShell, rect);
tf.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Center;

foreach (string item in quantityList)
{
    XRect lineRect = new XRect(340, yBase + yOffset, 30, 125);
    tf.DrawString(item, invoiceItemsFont, XBrushes.Black, lineRect, XStringFormats.TopLeft);
    yOffset += lineHeight;
}
```